# gcloud init generates bad url with 279.0.0

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I installed a fresh gcloud sdk (in Azure Cloud Shell if it matters...)

```
chad@Azure:~$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 279.0.0
bq 2.0.53
core 2020.01.31
gsutil 4.47
```

I'm trying to run 'gcloud init' -- but the URL it renders does not work...

```
chad@Azure:~$ gcloud init
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Your current configuration has been set to: [default]

You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
  gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.
Reachability Check passed.
Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

You must log in to continue. Would you like to log in (Y/n)?

Go to the following link in your browser:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?code_challenge= I REMOVED 
 A BUNCH OF CODES HERE &scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth


Enter verification code:
```

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: if it helps - used these instructions for install... https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive#linux

Comment: Could you please try with: `gcloud auth login`, and then try again?

Comment: @BraulioBaron same issue...

Comment: You have an incomplete URL that you are copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@John Hanley -- for the win!

Can't believe I didn't think of that -- thanks much.

Chad

p.s. looks like a bug in Azure Console or Windows Terminal truncating wrapped text...